# I can't reach the last node in Linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

I have a linked-list (actually stack, but implemented using LL), I can't reach the last node. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I searched all over StackOverflow but they wrote the same code as mine.

I have a head node.

```
struct stack{
    int no;
    stack *link;
};
stack *top1 = null;

int main(){
    while(top1->next!=NULL){
        cout << top1->no <<  endl;
        top1=top1->link;
    }
}

// I didn't add the rest of the code, because it's a part of my homework, and our teachers search the internet
```

And this makes sense, I traverse through my stack, but the last node has a *link pointer as NULL, so this loop stops there, and doesn't make anything about the last node.

How can I fix this? Surprisingly I couldn't reach the element with do-while loop either.

BTW I have 10 elements in stack, I can show them by this loop, and adding extra cout for the last node as:
cout << top1->no;

I have no problem with the elements but I have problems with traversal.

Thanks.

Comment: Make it 'while (top1 != NULL)'. You miss the last entry because of your current check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it

while (top1 != NULL)

You miss the last entry because of your current check and simply stop the element before your last one. 
You pretty much want to check if you reached the NULLpointer. If not, you 'eventually' are within a proper element of yours (or entirely wrong, if you fucked something up before).

Comment: Thanks. I dunno why I made this mistake, and unfortunately as i recall, I made the same mistake in the midterm too. :(

Comment: Don't worry, at some point you will have learned it by heart ;)